# Cannot find Keycloak OpenId client's client_secret

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid, keycloak

I was testing out Keycloak to use it as a SSO server for some OpenId clients that depend on Authorization Code Flow. Service providers such as Google or Facebook provide you both the "client id" and "client secret" so that at some point in the flow you can use them to get an access token.

But in Keycloak, I couldn't see the "client_secret" anywhere in the admin console or subsequent tabs after I finished creating clients.

[image: client configuation page]

Did I miss anything in the configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Public clients do not have client secret. You need to change your "Access type" to confidential. You also have to add at least one "Valid Redirect URIs" and click Save. After that tab "Credentials" will show up on second place with Client Secret.